# Gitlab CI/CD fails to build docker image

Tags: docker, gitlab, cicd, docker-registry

I have built a custom base image from alpine and use it as the base for ruby services that we develop.

```
FROM ruby:2.4.2-alpine
...
```

I use Gitlab and Gitlab's docker registry along with it. Each project has its own docker image storage.

I created a separate project for the **alpine-ruby-service** dockerfile. Then build and pushed the image to Gitlab.

In the ruby service project docker images, I reference it as follows

```
FROM gitlab.mycompany.dk/alpine-ruby-service-base
...
```

I have a CI/CD pipeline (.gitlab-ci.yaml) which builds these ruby service images when there is a commit to one of the branches.

The problem is that when the CI/CD pipeline is run it fails with the following message

```
 $ docker build --pull -t $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE .
   Sending build context to Docker daemon  709.6kB

 Step 1/13 : FROM gitlab.mycompany.dk:xxxx/alpine-ruby-service-base
 pull access denied for gitlab.mycompany.dk:xxxx/alpine-ruby-service-base,
 repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: 
 requested access to the resource is denied
```

I have an instruction to login to the Gitlab docker registry before the build command above using

```
 docker login --username=gitlab-ci-token --password=$CI_JOB_TOKEN gitlab.mycompany.dk:xxxx
```

the login succeeds but the following docker build instruction fails!!! can someone point me what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that the `docker login` and the `docker build` were done by different users. If a `docker login` is performed, then a `~/.docker` directory will be created in the namespace of user X, if the build is done by user Y then the latter user does not have a .docker folder and is not authorized to pull the image. One could verify this by `echo $USER` in the pipeline, in this case gitlab-ci.yaml to check this.

Comment: I tried to put the *echo $USER* in the .gitlab-ci.yml but it doesn't print anything. I tried to change the base image from *FROM gitlab.mycompany.dk/alpine-ruby-service-base* to docker hub public repository and it works. I checked the ~/.docker directory and all the registry login details are there.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be happening if you perform a `docker login` before the `docker pull` in a gitlab runnner as instructed if:

Your shell runner is configured to run multiple builds and all the builds share the same home directory /home/gitlab-runner-username. Per default `docker login` saves the credentials in ~/.docker/config.json. When there is multiple build jobs running the second build job may overwrite the credentials of the first one. When the second one is triggered by a different user or finishes before the first one, the first one may get the `denied:  requested access to the resource is denied` message even tough you logged in properly.

On our servers i solved this by using a custom [credentials script](https://gist.github.com/ap-wtioit/5e8379a1acc74affffe15f754ef1f6e1) that does not store the credentials in a shared file but uses the credentials present in the [gitlab ci job environment](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)